# Passing multiple parameters from jsp page to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

This may seem like a duplicate. But it isn't.

This is my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function popupwin(qid)
{
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=800, height=600");
    myWindow.document.write("<p> Qid = "+qid);
}
</script>

.......

<%
try{ 
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","Shravya17");
    ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from questions where category = ?");
    ps.setString(1,cat);

    rs=ps.executeQuery();  
    while(rs.next()){
        qid = rs.getInt(1);
        ques = rs.getString(2);
        cat = rs.getString(3);
        a = rs.getString(4);
        b = rs.getString(5);
        c = rs.getString(6);
        d = rs.getString(7);
        ca = rs.getString(8);
%>      
        <tr align = "center">
        <td> <%= qid %> </td> 
        <td> <%= ques %> </td>
        <td> <%= cat %>  </td>
        <td> <%= a %>  </td>
        <td> <%= b %>  </td>
        <td> <%= c %>  </td>
        <td> <%= d %>  </td>
        <td> <%= ca %>  </td> 
        <td>            
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick=(popupwin(<%=qid%>));/>
        </td>
        </tr>           
<%
    }
```

This works fine.

But how do I pass more than one parameter in the function call?

I tried passing parameters separated by commas but it didn't work.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

there is no reason it shouldn't work, I suspect you had a syntax error. try the following.

```
<td>            
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="(popupwin(<%=qid%>, 'test'))" />
</td>

function popupwin(qid, testVal) {
   console.log(testVal); // you should see 'test' in your browser's console
}
```

Comment: Turns out i hadn't used double quotes to specify the value of onclick. Although i don't know how i missed it.
Thank you!